# Pagify.js in Wordpress not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having trouble implementing [Pagify](http://bytemuse.com/Pagify/) in Wordpress.

First I tried [this tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/) to register the script in function.php. It worked, the pagify.js is included, and the jQuery too. FYI, I'm using wp-foundation themes, its has built-in jQuery.

and then I put the script to call pagify in the header.php before wp_head() and also i try after `wp_head()`:

```
$('#page_holder').pagify({
    pages: ['home', 'about', 'contact'],
    default: 'home' // The name of a page or null for an empty div
});
```

I created HTML just like in pagify tutorial, and my div container id is also named `page_holder`. but it doesn't work.

Second I tried to register the script above to function.php, but still didn't work.

Third, I modified pagify.js, add `noConflict()` but still not work.

Comment: Did you tried to call the script before wp_footer, in footer.php??

Answer (score 0):

I am always facing issues with adding jquery scripts to my WP sites and still don't find a general way to resolve them, so I do like you, I try the different possibilities: nonConflict, register scripts and enqueue  them, call them in simple `script` tags before wp_head or before wp_footer in header.php and footer.php respectively....

The last situation was to try to implement the Tag-it jquery plugin with my wordpress site and I resolved it by calling the script in my footer.php (I tell you beacause you didn't  mention you tried this option in your question).

**Example with Tag-it plugin:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/tag-it.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit(
        {
        fieldName: "tages[]"
        }
        );
    });
</script>

<?php
    /* Always have wp_footer() just before the closing </body>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to reference JavaScript files.
     */

    wp_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Hi whiteletters,its not working :(, i thing im gonna make my own jquery. thanks